# Laying LVP on a room notch

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

I have a room that is shaped like this:

```
         ┌──────────────────────────┐
         │LVP ->                    │
         │                          │
┌────────┘                          │
│        Notch                      │
│                                   │
│                                   │
│                                   │
│                                   │
│                                   │
└─────────────────┐               ┌─┘
                  │   Closet      │
                  └───────────────┘
```

I started laying out LVP at `LVP ->` and came to a situation where the notch does not line up with the rest of the extended width. What is the best way to lay the remaining LVPs? Some ideas I came with:

1. Rip cut the first row of LVPs so offset is matched.
2. Continue laying down the LVPs in the zig-zag pattern until the closet is reached
3. Start laying new LVPs from the right side of the room

Edited to add: I’m also adding LVPs to the closet

Actual photos are attached.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @dandavis make that an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @dandavis on a second thought: I had to make cuts to fit the air vent on the first two rows (top right). I think those two planks will be wasted if I go this route

Comment: you can still use most of the planks you cut for the vent, maybe all of them. You _will_ waste planks no matter what, so don't fret over it. Even if they all fit w/o cuts, you still _want_ to waste half of (at least) every-other row's end plank so that your small seams don't align. It's not worth it looking half-ass forever to save the cost of even a whole box of planks. Don't ask how i know...

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you'll not have to rip along the long wall as well, or are the plank's width a whole-number factor of the room "height" as shown in your diagram? If they do magically fit, then you only need to rip the planks that abut the notch. If they don't fit, then I would start over from the longer closet-side so you don't have to rip any parallel courses; you only have to rip in front of the notch and against the shorter wall.

Scribe it against the destination wall with a compass first so you have a perfect fitting line to trace. If no compass, you can also do it by placing a plank flush against the wall, then putting another plank backwards (face up) under it that lines up with the existing rows, so there's some long overlap. Trace along the edge of the overlap and cut. Now when you flip the plank to snap it to the existing course, it will magically fit right in against the wall.

You also should introduce random lengths to the rows, which you can use half your scraps for (the other half will be "wrong-handed"). That way every-other column doesn't line up, which will look amateur.

Comment: Sorry Dan, I should’ve mentioned that I’m also adding flooring to the closet

Comment: That doesn't change my advice, other than that you'll (maybe) have to also rip the row against the back closet wall, but that's still the least possible ripping.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have two choices:

1. Continue your layout the way you have it.  You'll need to rip some thinner pieces for the first row to the left of the notch (save the excess in case they can be used at the opposite wall), plus you'll have to notch out one plank at the corner of the notch.
2. Shift the planks you've already placed so that the edge is even with the wall left of the notch, and slip in some ripped planks (again, save the excess) to make up the difference at the window wall.

I wouldn't do random lengths—the manufacturers usually recommend a 1/3 offset.  Doing random lengths could void any warranty.

You're probably gonna need to remove the baseboard on the other side of the room and in the closet (if there is any there) to install the last of the LVP there.